# ListView - TAB navigate only through nested controls

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

I have a ListView with rows containing TextBlock and ComboBox.
I want to create keyboard TAB navigation that:

1. on TAB - focus switches between combo-box-es
2. rows (as a controls) are never selected

But by default ListView on TAB 1st select whole row and then focus on combo-box.

```
--------------
Select value:
[combo-box-1]
--------------
Select value:
[combo-box-2]
--------------
Select value:
[combo-box-3]
--------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default [TabNavigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.tabnavigation?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_TabNavigation) of ListView is **Once**, this means the container and all of its child elements as a whole receive focus only once, so you need to change it as Cycle or Local. In addition, if you don't want to select the items by pressing the Tab key, you need to set **IsTabStop** to false for each item, in this case, items won't be included in tab navigation.

xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" TabNavigation="Cycle" ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ......
</ListView>
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks!!! I added <ListView SelectionMode="None" .../> so rows are not clickable by mouse.